# How is total throughput value calculated in Aggregate Report?

Tags: jmeter

I discovered, that in Aggregate Report TOTAL THROUGHPUT value depends on thread count. And if we run tests with only one thread, total throughput is calculated as 1 / Total Average (and multiplied by 1000 to convert milliseconds to seconds, see the screenshot below). 
But when we set thread count to 2 or more, total throughput is calculated the unknown way, so what I want to know is which formula is used when calculating total throughput in this case (thread count > 1), because it does not seem to be an average of all requests throughput, it's also not calculated as 1 / Total Average like described in the first case. So how exactly does this work? (Screenshot for 2 threads attached below)
Thanks.

Screenshot for 1 thread used:
[aggregate_1_thread.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Odj4k.png)

Screenshot for 2 threads used:
[aggregate_2_threads.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8YtL.png)

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? If ok you should accept it so that it's useful to others

Answer (score 0):

As per doc:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report

> Throughput - the Throughput is measured in requests per second/minute/hour. The time unit is chosen so that the displayed rate is at least 1.0. When the throughput is saved to a CSV file, it is expressed in requests/second, i.e. 30.0 requests/minute is saved as 0.5.

So result depends both on Response time and Number of threads which influences those response times.

The total number of requests is divided by the time taken to run them, see:

- https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/visualizers/SamplingStatCalculator.java#L198

Comment: Could you give the formula?
Still unclear how this value is calculated.